# does std::unordered_map::reserve guarantee that no memory allocation will happen so long as there are fewer elements in the map?

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer, std, unordered-map

If I use std::unordered_map::reserve with the argument n, will inserting into the map be guaranteed to not cause a heap allocation so long as there are fewer than n elements inserted into the map?

Comment: Note that there's no requirement for `max_load_factor` to be one or more. You could face a rehashing even if half of your buckets are empty.

Answer (score 5):

No such guarantee appears to be in the standard.

Moreover if you look at an implementation - quoting the headers that come with gcc (<bits/hashtable.h>):

> In terms of Standard containers the hashtable is like the
> aggregation of:
>
> - `std::forward_list<_Node>` containing the elements
> - `std::vector<std::forward_list<_Node>::iterator>` representing the buckets

reserve makes sure that you have the appropriate number of buckets, it sizes that vector appropriately. So there will be no more allocations for new buckets at least. But the buckets are internally linked lists and inserting an element into one has to allocate a new _Node.

So overall: no, even after reserve with the appropriate capacity an unordered map may (and in the case of gcc **will**) allocate heap memory.